# How can i run a toolkit via java project instead of Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04

I'm really new in Java. I ran a toolkit via terminal.
I want to run it via a Java project. in the next step, I must bridge it to .net.
I have no idea about the process. please help me...

Thank You

Comment: What do you mean by "run it via a Java project"?

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1 is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to run your toolkit using Java. You can execute other process using Java's ProcessBuilder.

You can execute  your toolkit through Java using ProcessBuilder like,

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
p.command("cmd_to_start_toolkit", "args_if_any");
p.start();
```

Or, use the  Apache Commons Exec , it is simple and elegant to use.

```
    String toolkitCmd= "cmd_to_start_toolkit";
    CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(toolkitCmd);
    DefaultExecutor myexecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
    myexecutor.setExitValue(1);
    int exeValue= myexecutor.execute(commandLine);
```